# Find the value of minimize $A=\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^4}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)\left(x+y\right)}$

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, sum-of-squares-method

Given $x,y,z>0$ satisfy $x+y+z=1$. Find the value of minimize  $$\frac{x^4}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)\left(x+y\right)}+\frac{y^4}{\left(y^2+z^2\right)\left(y+z\right)}+\frac{z^4}{\left(z^2+x^2\right)\left(z+x\right)}$$

---

After use C-S and AM-GM i get $\frac{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2+1}$, help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x=y=z=\frac{1}{3}$ then we get a value $\frac{1}{4}$.

We'll prove that this is a minimal value.

Indeed, by C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^4}{(x^2+y^2)(x+y)}\geq\frac{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^2+y^2)(x+y)}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$\frac{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^2+y^2)(x+y)}\geq\frac{x+y+z}{4}$$ or
$$4(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2\geq(x+y+z)\sum_{cyc}(2x^3+x^2y+x^2z)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(2x^4-3x^3y-3x^3z+6x^2y^2-2x^2yz)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(2x^4-3x^3y-3x^3z+4x^2y^2)+\sum_{cyc}(2x^2y^2-2x^2yz)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^4-3x^3y+4x^2y^2-3xy^3+y^4)+\sum_{cyc}(x^2z^2-2z^2xy+y^2z^2)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2(x^2-xy+y^2)+\sum_{cyc}z^2(x-y)^2\geq0,$$
which is obvious.

Done!